# Macro hotkey for "Save Image As..." in Firefox?

Tags: autohotkey, firefox-extensions, logitech-keyboard, autoit, lua

#### Relevant PC info:

- Windows 7 64bit
- Firefox (latest)
- Logitech g710+ Keyboard with Logitech Gaming software

Right now, I have to:

1. Hover over an image
2. right-click
3. Click "*Save Image As..*"
4. Click "Save" on the explorer save window (and potentially go to desktop)

I instead want to be able to:

1. Hover over an image
2. Press the G4 button on my g710+ keyboard

My first choice would be a Firefox extension, followed by a Lua script (that's what Logitech Gaming Software allows you to use), followed by AutoIt (I can code up simple things), followed by Autohotkey (never used it before and not installed).

In the latter three cases I obviously don't expect code. My intention is only to find out if there is a Firefox extension out there, or a simpler solution that I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use The Key History in AutoHotKey to find out the ScanCode or keyname of your <kbd>G4</kbd> key to launch this. Alternatively, you could map the G4 key internally to e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> and use the 2nd hotkey option.
The script will only execute when Firefox is active. It will Launch the rightClick menu, then send <kbd>v</kbd>, wait for the save as window and click <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent

#IfWinActive, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
SC123::  ; or ^!#F12:: , select one of the two options
    Send,{RButton}
    Sleep, 30
    Send, v
    WinWaitActive, Save Image
    ControlSend, Button1, {Space} , Save Image
Return
#IfWinActive
```

#### Find the scancode:

Right Click on AutoHotKey Icon. Select `Open`, Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>, hit <kbd>G4</kbd>, then <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh the page and see the scancode for <kbd>G4</kbd> towards the bottom.

---

In AutoHotKey you can define hotkeys in multiple ways.
Examples:

```
a::Send, Hello World!
```

When you press <kbd>a</kbd> it will send "Hello World" to whatever is active on your screen right then.

```
F12::Send, Hello World!
```

Same but now for the <kbd>F12</kbd> key

```
^!#F12::Send, Hello World!
```

Same but now for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> key combination

```
F1::Send, {F12}
```

Would remap your <kbd>F1</kbd> key into the behaviour of the <kbd>F12</kbd> key

```
SC058::Send, Test
```

Uses ScanCode 058 (is the <kbd>F12</kbd> key) to send "Test".

```
:*:ahk::AutoHotKey
```

Expands <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> into the word AutoHotKey.

In your situation, you will have to decide which hotkey combination will trigger the script.

Here is some documentation:
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm

Oh, übrigens, the double `::` separates the hotkey from the action and the `;` is the comment separator. Grüsse.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What does the line: "SC123::  ; or ^!#F12:: , select one of the two options" do? I have never seen autohotkey code before so I'm just curious what double colon means and the semicolon